# How I can get duration of AVPlayer?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to make slider for my AVPlayer, I used AVPlayer because I want to stream a mp3 file from Firebase..

I tried:

```
var duration = player.currentItem.asset.duration
```

but that obviously doesn't work :)

I read the documentation of AVPlayer but I don't get it
There is `seek` function and I don't know how that work
In AVAudioPlayer there is duration function which show that information, but in AVPlayer there is nothing like unfortunately...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this.

I used currentTime in previous answer to get currentTime and convert that into seconds using CMTimeGetSeconds function.

But for get complete duration I just made a function getDuration:

```
func getDuration() -> String {
    
    var duration = audioManager.player?.currentItem?.asset.duration
    var getDurationString = DateComponentsFormatter.positional.string(from:CMTimeGetSeconds(duration!))
    
    return getDurationString!
}
```

and just call that function into my Text view.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you.

```
player.currentTime
```

Comment: I need just for total duration of audio file, example if my file is 3:34 long, I want to convert that into string type